# Some rows are randomly skipped while scrolling in a dynamic web table

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am doing Automation for a web app, on that I am getting issue with the scrolling,

I have tried with the below mentioned two different logic for scrolling,

1. scrollIntoView(true) - Some rows are randomly skipped while selecting,
2. Virtual keyboard press & release down arrow for every iteration, -  same issue in this also

The issue is not happening all the time, but its happening randomly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can try scroll down using JavascriptExecutor, enter the x and y co-ordinated in below code as per your requirement.

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("scroll(0,250);");
```

If you want to scroll to a element then use below code:

```
JavascriptExecutor je= (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
je.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```